# Firebase CloudMessage

Tags: iphone, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase Cloud Message

I can't receive the news, iPhoneX is particularly badly unable to receive the news, other mobile phones can, and the dependence on the network is quite serious, it is very confusing

Comment: Hi David. I think you need to put some more details into your question, such as the relevant bits of code you're using to pull the news, and exactly what errors/issues you're facing.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client?authuser=2

Comment: Perform client configuration as follows:https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client?authuser=2    , but The pushed client token can be sent to the server, but the message is very unstable. Trying to use Postman for configuration testing and Google Firebase console test push, the same is true. Some phones can receive some of them. The result is no problem printing the token.

Comment: Protocol document for Server: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream

Comment: Init Code :
public void InitMessaging(){
       Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
       Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;
}

Comment: This is a start, thank you, but this really needs to be properly formatted and put into your question if you want people to be able to help you. The question should give everything someone needs to help diagnose and address the problem, without them having to wade through the comments.

Comment: Thank you for not receiving the push problem. I solved the problem related to network stability.
But there is another problem. The callback does not work when accepting the message as follows:

Comment: public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    
    {
    
      TDebug.LogWarning("HOUHOU>>>>>>> Received a new message <<<<<<<<<<<");
    
      var notification = e.Message.Notification;
    
      if (notification != null)
    
      {
    
          TDebug.LogWarning("HOUHOU>>>>>>> title: " + notification.Title);
    
          TDebug.LogWarning("body: " + notification.Body);
    
      }
    
    }

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for not receiving the push problem. I solved the problem related to network stability.
But there is another problem. The callback does not work when accepting the message as follows:

```
public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
        TDebug.LogWarning("HOUHOU>>>>>>> Received a new message <<<<<<<<<<<");
        var notification = e.Message.Notification;
        if (notification != null)
        {
            TDebug.LogWarning("HOUHOU>>>>>>> title: " + notification.Title);
            TDebug.LogWarning("body: " + notification.Body);
        }
}
```

Warning: UNUserNotificationCenter delegate received call to -userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.

Comment: It's a small mistake. Unity is not the same as iOS Android. The life cycle of OnMessageReceived and the token callback function are also slightly different. The problem has been solved.